# Semi-Supervised Hierarchical Topic Model

Tags: hierarchical-clustering, topic-models, semi-supervised-learning

Problem statement:

I'm looking to label some data with topics. These topics have a hierarchical structure (3 layers deep at maximum, but I have leaf nodes 2 layers down as well) that I have been given. I also have ~definitions of each topic, which are basically a paragraph to page or two that describes the topic. I expect a good portion of my corpus does not fall under any topic in this heirarchy, so I'll expect to add in some outlier options or general catch-everything-else topics.

Background research:

I'm familiar with algorithms such as hLDA (hierarchical Latent Dirichlet Allocation) - these do not let you add your own structure to the problem (too unsupervised). I'm also familiar with algorithms such as guidedLDA (which allows you to define seed words for your priors), but this does not permit any hierarchical structure. In googling semi-supervised hierarchical topic modeling, the only algorithm I've come across (SSHLDA) is mentioned here: https://openreview.net/forum?id=SygD1GzdWS  however, it there doesn't seem to be any existing code implementation of the algorithm. I could attempt to code it up myself; but ideally I'm looking for an already existing solution. I've also contemplated using some existing heirarchical clustering algorithms that I'd modify to seed; not sure which approach is better.